# Are higher Chow groups and motivic cohomology isomorphic for smooth schemes over a Dedekind domain?

Tags: nt.number-theory, motivic-cohomology, dedekind-domains

Voevodsky famously [proved](https://www.math.ias.edu/Voevodsky/files/files-annotated/Dropbox/Published%20versions/motivic_cohomology_groups_are_isomorphic_published.pdf) that his motivic cohomology defined by presheaves with transfers was isomorphic to Bloch's higher Chow groups for smooth schemes over a field. There have long been constructions of the higher Chow groups over a Dedekind domain (e.g. [Geisser](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-004-0680-x), but I think originally due to Levine), and I've also seen Voevodsky-style constructions in over more general bases (see for example [Kerz's thesis](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj7yY2jhM-DAxWRJUQIHTP-BdwQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkerz.app.uni-regensburg.de%2Farticles%2Fmilnork_inventiones.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3jhNUJIj-RtDfV0oYQ_JkW&opi=89978449)) more recently. Is the isomorphism between the two known to extend to smooth schemes over a more general base?

Comment: This an open question in mixed characteristic. For smooth schemes over regular 1-dimensional bases, motivic cohomology is not defined using Voevodsky's construction, but it is the Zariski sheafification of Bloch's cycle complex, as in Geisser's paper (there are various other ways of defining it, but they all agree with this).